# Can't find objects with Find() in hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When game starts, script will close the shop.(SetActive(false))

```
void Start()
    {
        _shopMenu = GameObject.Find("Shop");

        _shopMenu.SetActive(false);

        if (_shopSlotContainer == null || _shopItemSlotTemplate == null)
            FindItemShopContainerAndItemTemplate();
    }
```

And try to find two objects on scene

```
private void FindItemShopContainerAndItemTemplate()
    {
        _shopSlotContainer = transform.Find("itemShopContainer");

        if (_shopSlotContainer == null)
            Debug.LogError("Container doesn't found");

        _shopItemSlotTemplate = transform.Find("shopItem_template");

        if (_shopItemSlotTemplate == null)
            Debug.LogError("Item template doesn't found");
    }
```

[image]

Any other ways to find objects or fix this problem?
(Script attached to "Shop" object)

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018270/findgameobjectswithtag-not-returning-objects/41018688#41018688), maybe this will give you some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform.Find will only search the immediate children, it will not look further down in the hierarchy. It is also not very performant. You can assign the game objects you want to variables in your script

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehavior
{
   [SerializeField]
   private GameObject _itemShopContainer {get; set;}
}
```

After compile you should be able to see Item Shop Container property on MyScript game object in the editor and be able to drag the proper game object there.
In the code _itemShopContainer will now have your game object.

If you want to assign via code like you are doing switch to using a variant of Transform.GetComponentsInChildren<>(), rather than Transform.Find

Comment: Thanks you so much, will try it

Comment: Yes, derHugo is right. I was misremembering the function. But GetComponentsInChildren<>() does exist and can be used for more performant searches through the object hierarchy. It will return the item as the specified component type, but I think .gameObject on any MonoBehavior will return the associated game object